# Showing wrong value of variable using Sql Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

```
$selectedItem = mysql_escape_string($_POST['select']);
$id= mysql_escape_string($_POST['id']);

if ($selectedItem == "ID")
    {
        echo 2;
        $nome = mysql_query("SELECT nome FROM `eventos` WHERE ID = '$id'");
        echo $nome;
    }
```

Ok, i want to show the name of one event of id that i insert in textbox.
It shows me 2, so if statement is working but when i say to show nome show me: 2Resource id #5

I have one row in table eventos with id = 1 and i put always in textbox number 1.

Why it doesnt show me the text that i have in collumn nome?

Comment: mysql_query function returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error according to the documentation. in your case, it returns success. try user3091574's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$n = mysql_fetch_array($nome);
echo $n['nome'];
```

It's recommended to use [mysqli_query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) instead of mysql_query

like this

```
 //
 $nome = mysqli_query("SELECT nome FROM `eventos` WHERE ID = '$id'");
 $n = mysql_fetch_array($nome);
    echo $n['nome'];
```